# Whitelisting IP for Magento admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, whitelist

Following the post:

> https://magento.com/security/best-practices/protect-your-magento-installation-password-guessing-new-update

I am not able to whitelist two public IPs of mine, while blocking other IPs for Magento admin panel. I have custom path set up for admin panel.

I have tried both:

```
# Whitelist an IP address for the admin panel
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xx.xx.xx.xx
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xx.xx.xx.xx
RewriteRule ^(index.php/)?admin/ - [L,R=403]
```

and:

```
# Whitelist an IP address for the admin panel
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xx.xx.xx.xx
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xx.xx.xx.xx
RewriteRule ^(index.php/)?custom-path-to-admin/ - [L,R=403]
```

But none of them seem to work, am I missing anything? (obviously xx.xx.xx.xx have been replaced with my public IP).

Comment: Actually if you read carefully they are NOT the same.

Comment: True that my bad, close vote retracted ;)

Comment: is your ip correctly identified by the server?

Comment: What do you mean by "correctly identified by the server"? I am sure the IP I put in there is correct.

Answer (score 0):

if your running your site over SSL "HTTPS", this will not work if mod_rewrite is not enabled on your server-ssl configuration